# Is there a way to use If-else statement instead of while loop?

Tags: java

EDIT: instead of any loops, i know this kind of statement needs a while loop but I was required to use only the If-else statement.

Im trying to find the largest digit in an inputted number and all examples i can see are using while and im a bit troubled in coding it using if else. this is my sample JAVA code:

```
Scanner cs1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Input three digit number : ");
        int num = cs1.nextInt ();
       
        int reminder, Largest_number= 0;
        
        while (num > 0)
        {
            reminder = num % 10;
           
            if (Largest_number< reminder) 
            {
                Largest_number= reminder;
            }
  


            num = num / 10;
        }
     
        System.out.println("\nOutput : "+Largest_number);
       
        cs1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to check every digit of the number if you don't want to loop over every digit of the number?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the number will be 3-digits?

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through that number `without loop`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cs1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input three digit number : ");
    int num = cs1.nextInt();

    int largestNumber = 0;



    System.out.println("\nOutput : " + getLargestNumber(Math.abs(num), largestNumber));

    cs1.close();
}

static int getLargestNumber(int num, int largestNumber){
    if (num>0){
        int reminder = num % 10;

        if (largestNumber < reminder) {
            largestNumber= reminder;
        }
        num = num/10;

        largestNumber = getLargestNumber(num, largestNumber);

    }
    return largestNumber;

}
```

What I am doing here is basically I am mimicing standard `for or while loops` with a thing called **recursion**.

From GeeksforGeeks:

> **What is Recursion?**  The process in which a function calls itself
> directly or indirectly is called recursion and the corresponding
> function is called as recursive function.

So I'm recursively calling static method `getLargestNumber(int num, int largest_number)` until I reach the moment when I do not enter `if (num>0)` statement.

And since calling of `getLargestNumber` is happening inside of that **if** statement, then the recursion stops, and I get the final result back.

**UPDATE**

You algorithm is wrong. You need to pass **Absolute** value of entered integer. Otherwise you algorithm will give wrong answer if you pass **negative** value as input.

Changed **num** to `Math.abs(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a solution without any kind of loop but only if there is guaranteed to have as input 3-digit numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner cs1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Input three digit number: ");
        String threeDigitNum = cs1.next();
       
        int largestNum, tmpNum;

        // assuming 1st digit is the largest
        largestNum = threeDigitNum.charAt(0) - '0';

        // checking if 2nd digit is greater than 1st
        tmpNum = threeDigitNum.charAt(1) - '0';
        if( tmpNum > largestNum ) 
            largestNum = tmpNum;
        
        // checking if 3nd digit is greater than 1st or 2nd
        tmpNum = threeDigitNum.charAt(2) - '0';
        if( tmpNum > largestNum ) 
            largestNum = tmpNum;

        System.out.println("\nOutput : "+largestNum);
       
        cs1.close();
    }
}
```

> Note:
> Any char is reprsented as an integer value, and that is what charAt() method returns. So from it subtracting the chrachter '0' (represented by it's integer value) it gives as a result the integer equivalent of that value. In case of digits, for example '8' - '0' will  result in integer value 8.